# Rewrite "I can’t understand what professor means" by changing verb (means) to noun

Tags: nominalization

> I can’t understand what the professor **means**.

If I rewrite that as:

> I can’t understand the professor’s **meaning**.

Does it seem different? Should I rewrite it?

Answer (score 1):

If you were referring to one specific thing that the professor said, and this was clear in context, they mean the same thing, although the second is more formal.

The first could also be used as a general complaint -- for instance, if the professor's thick accent meant lectures were generally unintelligible, you could complain that you can't understand what the professor means, but it would be odd to use the second.